# Python 'A bytes like object is required' when writing to stdin even after encoding

Tags: java, python, minecraft

My code is:

```
import subprocess, os

#just write the command to the input stream
process = None
minecraft_dir = '.'
executable = 'java -jar server.jar'
while True:
    command=input('cmd: ').encode()
    if command==(b"start"):
            os.chdir(minecraft_dir)
            process = subprocess.Popen(executable, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
            print("Server started.")
    else:
            print(command)
            print(command, file=process.stdin)
```

It always, always says a bytes-like object is required, even if I print it and it shows it is clearly in byte format, and also even the rare times I have gotten it to work, it still does nothing.

Why is this happening??

Comment: On what line do you get the error?

Comment: maybe you can try to explicitly set the encoding: 
_command=input('cmd: ').encode('utf-8')_ instead oj just _command=input('cmd: ').encode()_

Comment: `process = subprocess.Popen('valid command',...)` works for me, `process = subprocess.Popen(b'valid command',...)` produces a TypeError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `print` function computes the string representation of its input, adds a newline, and outputs that to a character stream. If you have a binary stream (like the `stdin` of your process), use `write`:

```
print(command) # This will output "b'USER INPUT'" (with a leading b')
process.stdin.write(command + b'\n')
```